# WordPress Directory Issue.(.htaccess)

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to deploy my application. To one subfolder on apache server. I have added required mime type to `.htaccess`. But still when i try to access that file in directory. I doesn't allow me to access my file.

.htaccess of root folder of my website.(i think it is default)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Also, my .htaccess for my folder is

```
AddType application/vnd.rim.cod

AddType  text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor

AddType  application/java-archive
```

Directly of wordpress(root)

```
/www/falconmediaworks.com
```

Directory of Folder.

```
/www/falconmediaworks.com/BlackBerry/Ytdhdbb
```

But this is working fine for me.

```
/www/falconmediaworks.com/google351f901143cfc116.html
```

File to be accessed.

```
/www/falconmediaworks.com/BlackBerry/Ytdhdbb/YTDHDBB.jad
```

Comment: The syntax of AddType is `AddType MIME-type extension [extension] ...`  If you don't specify the extensions, then the AddType does nothing.  This is why your jad doesn't work.

Comment: Please throw some light on other things. Mime is one issue but i think still i would be be able to download the file?

Comment: It looks like you've got a Virtual Private Server (VPS).  Why not enable rewrite logs and you can see why it goes wrong yourself.  Also try turning off MultiViews because a subquery could cause this screw-up.

Comment: No VPS, only hostgator shared hosting. These paths are from Filezilla

Answer (score 0):

I still can't make comments here for some reason so adding this as an answer even though it isn't one.  Have something similar with my installation of WP, I can't browser access files in sub directories unless they are chmodded (and all the parent directories) to 755 (I can programmatically access any file still).  I haven't got the foggiest why not and haven't been too bothered since my project is only a hobby and is quite small.  644 default (should be read access for anyone) I get File Not Found reported in my WP blog which I expect is what you're getting.  If anybody else does know wtf this is all about I'd like to know as well since even even though it's a hobby I'd like to get it right one day.

Comment: Oh I can comment on my own stuff.  The sub-directories are not subs of WP they are subs of root (though WP is in root).  Didn't have this issue until WP installed and is presumably some upshot of the WP .htaccess modifications.